# Defining layout columns with grid system vs directly to content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid, zurb-foundation

Instead of using a "grid system" (commonly seen in front end frameworks like Bootstrap or Foundation) to define page layouts is it okay (or considered better) to apply these layout styles to the content directly?

For example:

```html
<style>
  .row {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="product">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>Product description...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="product">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>Product description...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

VS

```html
<style>
  .products {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .product {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <p>Product description...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <p>Product description...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To me the 2nd example is the better option because it is more flexible. For example if I wanted to convert from a 2 column layout to a 4 column layout via a media query at larger screen size I can just change the width of `.product` to 25%. Where with the Bootstrap style grid system the width is set at the HTML level, I can't go changing my `.col-6` width because it is would be used in multiple locations across the page.

To my understanding that is why Foundation uses a `.large-#-columns`, `.medium-#-columns`, `.small-#-columns` so that you can define the column size/layout through media queries by targeting the medium at medium screen size, and the small at small screen sizes (though this is just me guessing could be completely wrong!).